# Existence of the solution of an ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

In the page 184 of the book "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" by H. Berezis, there is a theorem due to Cauchy, Lipschitz and Picard, which states that if $E$ be a Banach space and $F:E\to E$ be a Lipshitz map, then given any $u_0\in E$, there is a unique solution $u\in C^1([0,\infty);E)$ of the problem 
$$\frac{du}{dt}(t)=Fu(t)~~~~~on [0,\infty);~~~~u(0)=u_0.$$

I want to know what happens if domain of $F$ is not whole of $E$, and be just a convex (and possibly closed) set of $E$? Dose the theorem hold under this new condition? What dose happen for the solution $u$?

Any hint or comment is appreciated as well as giving any reference.

Comment: Then $u$ might leave the domain of $F$ at some point, and there's no reason one should expect more. Take for example $F(x)=x$ defined on $[0,5]$ and $u_0=1$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz Thank you for your comment. Your example shows an important fact about $u$, but about the existence of the solution, I think because we can extend the domain of $F(x)=x$ such that it satisfies all the conditions of the cited theorem , then existence of the solution still concludes from Cauchy-Lipschitz-Picard theorem. What dose happen when we could not do so? For example, consider $F:[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\to[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]; F(x):=x^2$. Then $F$ is not Lipschitz over the whole Banach space $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore the cited theorem dose not work anymore.

Comment: This can also be extended to a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb R$, for example by constant $1/4$. Actually, any Lipschitz function on a subset of $\mathbb R$ can be extended to the whole space.